# How should I handle problems downloading Maven dependencies in a Cloudbees Jenkins build?

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle, cloudbees

I have a Java project that I build in a Cloudbees Jenkins instance.  The build process uses Gradle and gets all of its dependencies from Maven repositories.  On a fairly regular basis, the build process has a problem downloading one or more dependencies from Maven Central.  Lately, it's been the appengine SDK:

```
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.23/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.23.pom

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':appengineSdk'.
> Could not determine artifacts for com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.23
   > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.23/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.23.zip'.
      > Could not HEAD 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.23/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.23.zip'.
         > The target server failed to respond

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

The URL is valid, it's just that sometimes repo1.maven.org, or some proxy in my path, seems to burp and the download fails.  A lot of the time (although not always, grrr...) if I go in and kick off the build manually, the download problem is resolved and the build succeeds.

In a standalone Jenkins instance (not at Cloudbees) this is not as big of a deal, because I can maintain a a Gradle cache and I only have to download dependencies once.  Because my Cloudbees environment typically gets refreshed for every build (re-downloading everything) the build fails a lot of the time that it runs.

I am looking for suggestions on the best way to handle this in the Cloudbees environment.  For instance:

- Can I cache some or all dependencies in my Cloudbees environment?
- Can I invoke a Gradle command to download all dependencies up front?
- Can I write a Gradle task to download dependencies and retry appropriately?
- etc.

I don't mind writing a custom Gradle task if that's what it takes, but I'm not quite sure where to start.  So, if that's the answer, pointers to documentation are appreciated, and I'll post my final implementation as an alternate answer.

Comment: P.S. I thought maybe I could handle this by unsetting the 'Force GRADLE_USER_HOME' option for the build.  This lets the cache live in the user ~/.gradle.   There is a slight improvement, since the cache  doesn't need to be recreated for every build.  However, I seem to get different slave build servers (and home directories) over time, and so dependencies do still need to be downloaded for a lot of builds.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a private repo instance that will proxy maven.org?

Comment: Are you suggesting that this is possible with a [Cloudbees Private Maven Repository](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/CloudBees+Private+Maven+Repository), or that I should set up my own Maven repository independent of Cloudbees?  I've looked over the Cloudbees documentation, and I don't see a way to set up one of their private maven repositories to proxy maven.org... so if that's what you're suggesting, can you point me at a reference?